# How to proxy apache to middleman server

Tags: php, apache, mod-proxy, middleman

I'm developing a frontend application with Middleman on a pre-existing php backend. In the production server my app will be a subfolder of the main app, but during the development phase I wish to keep the two app completely separated.

I have installed the php app in my local apache. Now I want apache to proxy the middleman app path to the middleman server.

I tried with:

```
<Location /phpapp/static>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:4567/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:4567/
</Location>
```

and bind middleman server to 127.0.0.1

but I get "Not Found: /"

I think this response comes from the middleman because, if I turn off the middleman server, apache responds with a "Service unavailable".

So, how can I have middleman server to send its contents through apache?

Comment: Now I have made it to partially work following this https://gist.github.com/kaplan/7253743 using mod_passenger... but now I can't manage to get css and js.

Comment: It will not be easy to do that, Mir. Apache tries to serve assets, but you need to make it actually delegate the connection to Middleman. I'm sure there's a way to do that, but you'll have a hard time finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it by modifying the configuration in this way.

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Location /phpapp/static>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:4567/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:4567/
  ProxyPreserveHost On
</Location>
```

The attempt I made using passenger failed because of dynamic assets that weren't served by Apache.